# iTunes: Getting updated meta-data onto iPod when using manual management

Tags: iphone, itunes, sync, ipod, metadata

OK, it's with an iPhone 3GS rather than an iPod, but same deal...

I'm manually managing the music on my iPhone (mainly because I don't understand the automatic management option), so I drag-drop from the iTunes library onto the iPhone and the files are copied across.

Problem is when I change the meta-data (tags) of a track in iTunes, it doesn't get updated on the phone no matter how many syncs I do. The only way I could get it updated was to drag-drop the files again.

1. Is there no way to make this updating happen during a sync when using manual management?
2. Does it get updated during a sync when you use automatic management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **1. Is there no way to make this updating happen during a sync when using manual management?**

If you have set your iPhone to manually manage your music, the only way to update the meta-data is to drag-and-drop the songs again, just like you said.

> **2. Does it get updated during a sync when you use automatic management?**

Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic management will sync everything. All it does is it will copy all your music into the iTunes folder under Music, and whenever you change the Meta-Data change the actual folder structure accordingly. In my honest opinion it's is the best meta data manager you can find, as songs are sorted and ordered by Artist -> Album. It also follow supports compilations and you can split them out.

Comment: +1 For automatic music management. It's really harmless, and if you don't want all your music to sync, you can just make a playlist (I'd suggest a Smart Playlist) in iTunes, and sync just that.